# TeamCity + HG. Only pull (push?) passing builds

Tags: mercurial, teamcity

Feels like with the popularity of continuous integration this one should be a piece of cake but I am stumped.  I am setting up TeamCity with HG.  I want to be able to push changesets up to a repository that TeamCity watches and runs builds on changes.  That's easy.

Next, if a build passes, I want that changeset to be pulled into a "clean" repository... one that contains only passing changesets. Should be easy but...

TeamCity 6 supports multiple build steps and if any step fails, the rest don't run.  My thought was to put a build step at the end that does a pull (or optionally a push?) to get the passing changeset into the clean repository.

I am trying to use PsExec to run hg on the box with the repositories.

If I try to run just a plain 'hg pull' it can't find the hg.exe even though it is set in the path and I have used the -w flag.

I have tried putting a .bat file in the clean repository that takes a revision parameter and it works fine... locally.  When I try to run the .bat file remotely (using PsExec) it runs everything fine but it tries to run it on the build agent.  Even if I set the -w argument it runs the .bat file there but tries to run the contents on the build agent box.

Am I just WAY off in my approach?  Seems like this is a pretty obvious thing to do so either my Google skills are waning or no one thinks this is worthy of writing about.  Either way, I am stuck in SVN land trying to get out so I would appreciate some help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the following lines to your powershell profile:

```
function hg {
    cmd /c hg.exe $args
}
```

If it doesn't recognize `hg.exe`, you may need to add it to your Path:

```
$env:Path = $env:Path + ";C:\Program Files\TortoisHG\";
```

(You can just type `notepad $profile` into the command prompt. it will open the file for you to edit in Notepad. Copy&paste this line and then save, exit.)

(see [PowerShell alias syntax for running a cmd.exe builtin function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4753919))

Answer (score 1):

Instead of running the command directly, have you tried running it under a shell instead?  This will make sure you get the environment variables which you are expecting.  If you don't use the command shell, it will execute the command directly without setting the environment so you would have to fully specify the path to the hg executable.

Try a commandline for psexec such as: `psexec c:\windows\system32\cmd.exe /c hg.exe`

Adding in the machine name and hg subcommand appropriately, of course.

Comment: Then you should mark this as the answer...ish.  What's ish about it for you?

Comment: Sorry... tried to do that last night after posting this but Stack went down for maintenance about 30 seconds after I posted. :)   I had to make sure the TeamCity service was running under an account with access to the remote box.  The only thing that I am stuck on is that if you run psexec with -d it returns an exit code of the PID that it started.  If you run it without the -d it hangs indefinitely.  Unfortunately TeamCity depends on an exit code of 0 to determine a pass / fail.  Thanks for the tip though, it got the thing to actually run the batch file and that's what I was stuck on.

Comment: Ah.  I've personally had issues with psexec's inability to handle some interactive remote commands (for example, don't bother trying to run powershell remotely via an interactive psexec session).  There are alternative tools which don't have such a limitation, although I have little experience with them.  You might investigate RCE: http://rce.sourceforge.net/ as well as rctrlx: http://sites.google.com/site/4utils/projects.  I've only used rctrlx (it takes the /cm option) but it has worked for me where psexec didn't.