# PowerShell alias syntax for running a cmd.exe builtin function?

Tags: powershell, alias

As I have only recently switched to PowerShell from `cmd.exe`, I often find it convenient to do little things in a familiar way by calling `cmd` to do them.  For instance, to do a 'bare' file listing this works great:

```
PS> cmd /c dir /b
dir1
dir2
file1.txt
```

I'd like to make an alias for this but I can't figure out the right syntax.  So far I've tried:

```
PS> Set-Alias dirb cmd /c dir /b        # error (alias not created)
PS> Set-Alias dirb "cmd /c dir /b"      # fail (alias doesn't work)
PS> Set-Alias dirb "cmd `"/c dir /b`""  # fail (alias doesn't work)
```

Any suggestions?  I'm looking for a general solution to calling builtin `cmd.exe` commands (such as `dir`).  I'd also like to know how to produce bare output the right way using PowerShell cmdlets, but that's a secondary concern at the moment.  This question is about the proper syntax for calling `cmd.exe` from an alias.

Comment: I think the same in Powershell is `dir | foreach { $_.name }`

Comment: `dir -Name` is also pure PowerShell.

Comment: @Roman, thanks for the pure posh answer!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe what you want is a function, not an alias. For instance:

```
  function dirb {
    cmd /c dir $args[0] /b
     }
```

From a PS prompt, run notepad $profile, paste that into your profile and then it will load automatically when you open a PS console and you can do this:

dirb c:\somedir

See get-help about_functions for more information about functions.

Comment: Works great, I also used `@args` rather than `$args[0]` so my function can accept multiple arguments.

Answer (score 4):

Aliases are not designed for this kind of tasks. An alias is just another name of a command. Use the function instead.

```
function dirb { cmd /c dir /b }
```

Answer (score 0):

Aliases in powershell don't take parameters unfortunately - you need to define a function for this. For more info,

```
get-help aliases
```

Comment: Thanks, I know PS aliases don't take parameters but I was hoping that an alias would be more like a macro: pure text substitution, where the substituted text could contain spaces.  I suppose that's why they're called 'aliases' and not 'macros'.

Answer (score 0):

Why on earth would you use powershell to open the command prompt? That seems to be defeating the purpose.

The Alias I prefer to list out files  is simply `ls`

Comment: One reason you might want to:[PS] C:\>measure-command {ls c:\windows -recurse -name} | select totalseconds | ft -auto

TotalSeconds
------------
  46.8366258


[PS] C:\>measure-command {cmd /c dir c:\windows /b /s} | select totalseconds | ft -auto

TotalSeconds
------------
   5.3308489

Comment: There are many reasons. And `cmd` in the question might be only an example of any native application.